# How to implement resend code functionality in scheb/2fa?

Tags: symfony

I have implemented two-factor authentication based on email code in my app. After user enter his email and password, system redirects him to /2fa route where he need to enter code from email. Everything works great. But I don't understand how to implement resend code functionality. The small advice [in doc](https://github.com/scheb/2fa/blob/5.x/doc/providers/email.md#re-send-authentication-code) isn't enough for me. Please help.

**Bundle version**: scheb/2fa-bundle: 5.10.1, scheb/2fa-email: 5.10.1
**Symfony version**: 5.2.10
**PHP version**: 8.0.3

config/packages/security.yaml

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            # target: app_any_route
            
        access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler

        two_factor:
            auth_form_path: 2fa_login    # The route name you have used in the routes.yaml
            check_path: 2fa_login_check  # The route name you have used in the routes.yaml
        
        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: '^/2fa', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_2FA_IN_PROGRESS }
    - { path: '^/login', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: '^/logout', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: '^/register', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: '^/reset-password', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: '^/verify/email', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: '^/', roles: ROLE_USER }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

config/packages/scheb_2fa.yaml

```
scheb_two_factor:
    security_tokens:
         - Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken
    email:
        enabled: true
        mailer: 2fa_mailer
        template: security/2fa_form.html.twig
        digits: 6
```

config/routes.yaml

```
2fa_login:
    path: /2fa
    defaults:
        _controller: "scheb_two_factor.form_controller:form"

2fa_login_check:
    path: /2fa_check
```

Comment: Autowire Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Provider\Email\Generator\CodeGeneratorInterface $codeGeneratorInterface in your Controller or Service and do $codeGeneratorInterface->reSend($user)

Comment: thanks @TimZwinkels your comment helped me to understand how it should works. Because before it I thought to implement custom controller for form rendering.

Answer (score 1):

To resend a 2-factor-auth-code feel free to inject

```
Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Provider\Email\Generator\CodeGeneratorInterface $codeGenerator
```

to your Controller or Service.

After this, you can call:

```
$codeGenerator->reSend($user)
```

Feel free to see the documentation:
https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/blob/4.x/Resources/doc/providers/email.md#re-send-authentication-code